# Complex shape with rainbow gradient

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a figure on a canvas, to be filled with a rainbow-colored gradient. The wanted result is something like this:

[image: Wanted result]

Creating the shape itself is pretty easy, just creating a path and drawing the lines. However, actually filling it with a gradient appears to be somewhat more difficult, as it seems only radial and linear gradients are supported.

The closest I have gotten is this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,100);
gradient.addColorStop (0, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop (0.25, 'yellow');
gradient.addColorStop (0.5, 'green');
gradient.addColorStop (0.75, 'blue');
gradient.addColorStop (1, 'violet');
ctx.moveTo(0,40);
ctx.lineTo(200,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.lineTo(0, 50);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
 </body>
```

The gradient colors and such are correct, but the gradient should of course be more triangular-like, rather than being rectangular and cropped.

Comment: I don't know for sure if it will work, but a thought: You could make a regular rectangle, put the gradient on it, and then skew and scale it using `transform`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations#Transforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native html5 canvas doesn't have a way to stretch one side of a gradient fill.

**But there is a workaround:**

Create your stretch gradient by drawing a series of vertical gradient lines with an increasing length.

[image]

Then you can use transformations to draw your stretched gradient at your desired angle

[image]

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var length=200;
var y0=40;
var y1=65
var stops=[
    {stop:0.00,color:'red'},
    {stop:0.25,color:'yellow'},
    {stop:0.50,color:'green'},
    {stop:0.75,color:'blue'},
    {stop:1.00,color:'violet'},
];

var g=stretchedGradientRect(length,y0,y1,stops);

ctx.translate(50,100);
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/10);
ctx.drawImage(g,0,0);


function stretchedGradientRect(length,startingHeight,endingHeight,stops){
    var y=startingHeight;
    var yInc=(endingHeight-startingHeight)/length;
    // create a temp canvas to hold the stretched gradient
    var c=document.createElement("canvas");
    var cctx=c.getContext("2d");
    c.width=length;
    c.height=endingHeight;
    // clip the path to eliminate "jaggies" on the bottom
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.moveTo(0,0);
    cctx.lineTo(length,0);
    cctx.lineTo(length,endingHeight);
    cctx.lineTo(0,startingHeight);
    cctx.closePath();
    cctx.clip();
    // draw a series of vertical gradient lines with increasing height
    for(var x=0;x<length;x+=1){
        var gradient=cctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,y);
        for(var i=0;i<stops.length;i++){
            gradient.addColorStop(stops[i].stop,stops[i].color);
        }
        cctx.beginPath();
        cctx.moveTo(x,0);
        cctx.lineTo(x,y+2);
        cctx.strokeStyle=gradient;
        cctx.stroke();
        y+=yInc;
    }
    return(c);
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Stretched gradient made from vertical strokes</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=200></canvas>
```